# How to design a SPICE model from data sheet?

Tags: spice, ltspice, multisim, simulation

I am new to SPICE simulation and I am looking for spice model file of `LTC 1065` data sheet can be found here [here](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1065fb.pdf).

I searched a lot on Google but I could not find much help about how one can design a SPICE model from data sheet.

I really don't know whether I can design or a SPICE model or not from the data sheet.

Comment: This doesn't answer the core of your question, but Linear Technologies (the company that makes the LTC1065) has a free SPICE program called LTSpice that has all their components modeled already. The interface is a little hokey, but it's otherwise a pretty good circuit simulator.

Comment: Thanks @DanLaks i am using LTSpice only and LTC1065 is not available in its library...

Answer (score 2):

The LTC1065 is 5th order Bessel lowpass filter in switched-capacitor technology. You are asking if it is possible to create a SPICE model by yourself - and my answer is: In principle - yes 
However, I would not recommend even to start such a project. Surely, it is a lot of work and it requires a deep knowledge of filter theory as well as switched-capacitor techniques. Use your time for other interesting tasks.

**EDIT:** 
I think, it is also important if you are interested in a model which can be used in the time domain (TRAN analysis) and/or in the frequency domain (ac analysis). In the latter case, it seems to be a bit easier to model the filter. In this case, you need no switches but time-continuous equivalent circuits which are available.

More than that, are you interested in particular in the LTC chip or - in general - in a 5th order filter?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. i know its difficult but could you tell me some idea how can i design it. and i have good knowledge in filters and switched-capacitor techniques

Comment: Do you have the proper equipment to test your model against real measurements? You may be able to write your model. But, because nothing is never right the first time, you may have "bugs" in your fisrt model, only comparisons with another provided model (even mathematical) or against real measurement using the real chip could ensure that your model is right.

Comment: yes. i have a real model.

Comment: user2851655: I have edited my answer (supplement). Have a look.

Comment: thanks. i need LTC only. Actuallly I am making a simulation of my real setup and for that i need LTC 1065 spice model.